# spark Not able to read from s3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am creating my spark-shell using the below command.

`spark-shell --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.392,org.wso2.orbit.joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4.wso2v1`

Then I am running the below code to access a file in S3.

```
val accessKeyId = "myid"
val secretAccessKey = "mykey"
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey",secretAccessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
val lines = sc.textFile("s3a://bucket-name/path-to-file")
```

Now runnning the below code gives me the below error.

```
scala> lines.count()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158612/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-reloadexisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to find dependency of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities`. Use

```
hadoop-common-3.1.jar
```

Comment: Now I am getting a different error. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158612/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-reloadexisting It is related to some version problem

Answer (score 0):

Your stack traces are exactly what happens when you try to mix hadoop-* JARs. you can't do that. All you will do is move stack traces around.

This is covered in [the latest s3a docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html)

ps: those aren't the property names for the s3a login details. Read that hadoop documentation